# Is there a function in Python for counting the number of outputs created from a 'for' loop with a break?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, output, spyder

I have written a "for" "in" "range" loop in python, and placed a "break" function for the loop to end at a specific condition. I need to produce a count for how many iterations the loop makes before it stops at the break point, but I can't find the right function. Any ideas?

I have attempted to create a list of the the range() values, and then use the len() function to get a count, but the range() list doesn't recognize the break function, and it just gives me a list of every iteration until the range ends.

```py
    for val in range(Nmax):    
        x_n1 = x_n - f(x_n)/fprime(x_n)

        print(x_n1)

        if( abs((x_n1 - x_n) / (0.5 * (x_n1 +x_n))) < delta ):
            break
        x_n = x_n1
```

The output is a list of numbers for each successful iteration. I need to produce an additional output that provides a count of all of the outputs before the break is hit.

Comment: Hello @abfeldy ! If any of the answers has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `range`, `val` will count loop iterations.

```
for val in range(Nmax):    
    x_n1 = x_n - f(x_n)/fprime(x_n)

    print(x_n1)

    if( abs((x_n1 - x_n) / (0.5 * (x_n1 +x_n))) < delta ):
        break
    x_n = x_n1

print(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use enumerate to have the index of the loop:

```
for i, val in enumerate(range(Nmax)):    
    x_n1 = x_n - f(x_n)/fprime(x_n)

    print(x_n1)

    if( abs((x_n1 - x_n) / (0.5 * (x_n1 +x_n))) < delta ):
        break
    x_n = x_n1

print(i)
```

Comment: In general, `enumerate` is the best way to get a loop counter, but when using `range`, `i` and `val` will always be the same number so you can simply use `val`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a counter to your code.

```
counter = 0
for val in range(Nmax):
    x_n1 = x_n - f(x_n)/fprime(x_n)
    if( abs((x_n1 - x_n) / (0.5 * (x_n1 +x_n))) < delta ):
        counter += 1
        break
    x_n = x_n1

print(counter)
```

You can then call the print function afterwards. Just make sure not to define your counter inside of your for loop, else it will reset with every iteration.